# Android Unit Testing a custom alertDialog

Tags: android, unit-testing, google-maps, android-alertdialog

I am in the process of building a unit test for a custom alert dialog box.  It is launched from a ItemizedOverlay onTap event which is called from our Map Activity.  My question is, is it possible from a unit test to get the View items from the inflated custom dialog box.

The dialog will show some buttons if properties are present and others if it is not.  This is the functionality that I am trying to test.